# How can I get one array to return only the masked values define by another array with Numpy / PyTorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a `mask`, which has a shape of: `[64, 2895]` and an array `pred` which has a shape of `[64, 2895, 161]`.

`mask` is binary with only `0`s and `1`s. What I want to do is reduce `pred` so that it maintains `64` batches, and along the `2895`, wherever there is a `1` in the `mask` for each batch, return the related `pred`.

So as a simplified example, if:

```
mask = [[1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]
pred = [[[0.12, 0.23, 0.45, 0.56, 0.57],
         [0.91, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.95],
         [0.24, 0.46, 0.68, 0.80, 0.15]],

        [[1.12, 1.23, 1.45, 1.56, 1.57],
         [1.91, 1.98, 1.97, 1.96, 1.95],
         [1.24, 1.46, 1.68, 1.80, 1.15]],

        [[2.12, 2.23, 2.45, 2.56, 2.57],
         [2.91, 2.98, 2.97, 2.96, 2.95],
         [2.24, 2.46, 2.68, 2.80, 2.15]]]
```

What I want is:

```
[[[0.12, 0.23, 0.45, 0.56, 0.57]],

 [[1.12, 1.23, 1.45, 1.56, 1.57],
  [1.91, 1.98, 1.97, 1.96, 1.95]],

 [[2.24, 2.46, 2.68, 2.80, 2.15]]]
```

I realize that there are different dimensions, I hope that that's possible. If not, then fill in the missing dimensions with `0`. Either `numpy` or `pytorch` would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a vectorized computation then different dimension seems not possible, but this would give you the one with masked entry filled with 0:

```
# pred: torch.size([64, 2895, 161])
# mask: torch.size([64, 2895])

result = pred * mask[:, :, None] 
# extend mask with another dimension so now it can do entry-wise multiplication
```

and `result` is exactly what you want